# How to do multi-key lookups using data.table?

Tags: r, merge, data.table, lookup

I am using data.table to do some repeated lookups on a large dataset (45M rows, 4 int columns).

Here is what I want to do.

```
library(data.table)
# generate some data, u's can show up in multiple s's
d1 <- data.table(u=rep(1:500,2), s=round(runif(1000,1,100),0))
setkey(d1, u, s)

# for each u, I want to lookup all their s's
us <- d1[J(u=1), "s", with=F]
# for each of the s's in the above data.table, 
#   I want to lookup other u's from the parent data.table d1

# DOESN'T WORK:
otherus <- d1[J(s = us), "u", with=F]   

# THIS WORKS but takes a really long time on my large dataset:
otherus <- merge(d1, us, by='s')
```

Merge works for my purpose but since my 'd1' >>> 'us', it takes a long time. At first I thought maybe I am using the merge from the base, but based on the docs it does look like data.table merge is dispatched is the class(first_arg to merge) is a data.table.

I am still getting used to data.table J() syntax. Is there a niftier way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ouch, those names are confusing. Shouldn't `us` refer to multiple `u`'s, not multiple `s`'s associated with a paticular `u`? Anyway, this sounds like graph theory to me. You're finding neighbors, right? IF so, you might want to look into the `igraph` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the key for that purpose.

```
setkey(d1,s,u)
```

After that command all `u` values for the same `s` value are grouped together.

```
        u   s
   1:  20   1
   2:  35   1
   3:  36   1
   4:  87   1
   5: 123   1
  ---        
 996: 208 100
 997: 262 100
 998: 352 100
 999: 430 100
1000: 455 100
```

Operations performed on the groups defined by the key columns usually work really fast, e.g.

```
d1[,mean(u),keyby='s']
```

If you need to do fast aggregation for both groups `u`and `s`, you could store two instances of the `data.table`. For one you use `setkey(d1,u,s)` and for the other `setkey(d1,s,u)`. If you want to perform operations quickly on the groups defined by the values of `u` use the former data.table otherwise the latter.

Comment: Thanks @Georg. I've actually done that-- basically 2 copies of the data.table with different key combinations. The datasets are big & I need to do this in a foreach loop which I believe makes a copy for each 'worker' so the RAM fills up quickly. I was hoping there was another solution. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Well, maybe it is possible to store only the index columns `u`and `s` plus a row identifier in two data.tables to save memory and combine it somehow with the `bigmemory` package which allows to store matrices in shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following work?

```
d1 <- data.table(u=rep(1:500,2), s=round(runif(1000,1,100),0))
setkey(d1, u, s)
us <- d1[J(u=1), "s"]
otherus <- merge(d1, us, by='s') 

setkey(d1,s)
otherus2 <- d1[us]
identical(otherus2, otherus)

setkey(d1, u, s)
```